# Sudden Auth Error ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (743: unexpected token at ''):

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have a Rails 5 api-only application.  Everything, authentication as well as post and get paths had been working, but suddenly, I am getting this error

```
ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (743: unexpected token at ''):
```

I have gone back to previous versions and still get the same error.

I have no idea where to even start looking. Here is the trace:

````
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/dariusgoore/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:




ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (743: unexpected token at ''):

actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:117:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:111:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:381:in `block in POST'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/request.rb:59:in `fetch'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/request.rb:59:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:380:in `POST'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:55:in `parameters'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:290:in `_wrapper_enabled?'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:244:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.3) lib/rack/cors.rb:95:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
```puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
````

Comment: Never mind, somehow this error occurs when using Postman parameters, but disappears using raw json..

Comment: Actually, request needed to include user credentials